# Find the first black pixel in every row with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

For every row in an image, I would like to find the first black (or first non-white) pixel in that row. For example, for an image like this:

[image]

I would expect output like:

```
0
1
0
```

Or something close to that that I can parse. I think there might be a way to do this with subimage-search but I don't quite know how. Any pointers?

Comment: So what do you want to return for a row of white-only pixels?

Comment: The very question was on the tip of my tongue :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do NOT need ***subimage-search*** to achieve your goal. The problem can be reduced to ***text parsing***.

### 1. Basics

Consider this: you can tell ImageMagick to convert any image to a textual representation, which holds the exact color information for each individual pixel. **Example:**

```
convert wizard: textwizard.txt
```

<sub>(`wizard:` is a builtin image available for all ImageMagick installations for testing purposes.)</sub>

Yes, it is that easy! This image "format" is requested by just adding a `.txt` suffix. **Results:**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 480,640,255,srgb
0,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
1,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
2,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
[....]
47,638: (246,247,249)  #F6F7F9  srgb(246,247,249)
48,638: (246,247,249)  #F6F7F9  srgb(246,247,249)
47,639: (236,235,236)  #ECEBEC  srgb(236,235,236)
48,639: (230,228,218)  #E6E4DA  srgb(230,228,218)
[....]
476,639: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
477,639: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
478,639: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
479,639: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

If you look at the first line of the output, you'll notice that ImageMagick uses it to detail some special info about the image here:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 480,640,255,srgb
```

It means:

- the image is 480 pixels wide,
- the image is 640 pixels high,
- the image uses a range of 0-255 for color info per channel (that is equivalent to an 8-bit color depth),
- the image is build in the sRGB color space

The other lines consist of 4 columns:

1. the first column in format `(N,M)` indicates the exact position of the respective pixels as `(row_number,column_number)`. *(The index for row and column numbers is zero-based -- row no. 1 is indicated as `0`, no. 2 as `1`.)*
2. the other three columns, redundantly, each hold the exact same information, each in a different notation: the exact color value for the pixel given in column 1. *(The last column will use a human-readable name if ImageMagick knows one for that color value...)*

> <sub>As a side note: you can use such a textual representation of the original image (with or without some extra modifications) to re-create a real image:</sub>
>
> ```
> convert textwizard.txt wizard.jpg
> ```

### 2. Select a specific row

You should be aware that you can select a specific region of an image with the following syntax:

```
image.png[WIDTHxHEIGHT+X_OFFSET+Y_OFFSET]
```

So to select a specific row only, you can set `HEIGHT` as `1`. To get any row completely, set `X-OFFSET` as `0`. To get a specific row, set the  `Y-OFFSET` accordingly.

In order to get the values (for the builtin `wizard:` image used above) for the row with index 47, we can do:

```
convert wizard:[640x1+0+47] row47.txt

cat row47.txt
 # ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 480,1,255,srgb
 0,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
 1,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
 2,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
 [....]
 428,0: (82,77,74)     #524D4A  srgb(82,77,74)
 429,0: (169,167,168)  #A9A7A8  srgb(169,167,168)
 430,0: (232,231,228)  #E8E7E4  srgb(232,231,228)
 432,0: (246,247,249)  #F6F7F9  srgb(246,247,249)
 [....]
 476,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
 477,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
 478,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
 479,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

If you do not want the textual output in a file, but printed on the standard output channel, you can do this:

```
convert wizard:[480x1+0+47] txt:-
```

### 3. Stitching it all together

Based on above snippets of information, the approach that can be taken with this task is clear:

1. Loop through all pixel rows of the image.
2. Output each pixel's color value as text.
3. Look for the first non-white pixel and keep its location information.

### 4. Possible script (OS X, Linux, Unix)

Here is a main part of a Bash script that could be used:

```
# Define some image specific variables (width, height, ...)
image=${1}
number_of_columns=$(identify -format '%W' ${image}) 
width=${number_of_columns}                        # just an alias
number_of_rows=$(identify -format '%H' ${image})
height=${number_of_rows}                          # just an alias
max_of_indices=$(( ${height} -1 ))

# Loop through all rows and grep for first non-white pixel
for i in $(seq 0 ${max_of_indices}); do
   echo -n "Row ${i} :  " ;
   convert ${image}[${width}x1+0+${i}] txt:- \
     | grep -v enumeration                   \
     | grep -v '#FFFFFF' -m 1                \
   || echo "All WHITE pixels in row!"  
done
```

The `-v white` will de-select all lines which contain the string `white`.
The `-m 1` parameter will return the maximum of 1 matches (i.e. the first match).

It will be slow, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks, I went with a similar approach, I use python instead because I already was doing a bunch of other stuff there. Text processing is definitely the way to go for this though.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something like this using the built-in checkerboard pattern:

```
convert -size 100x100 pattern:checkerboard -auto-level board.png
```

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
convert wizard: txt: | awk -F'[,: ]' '
   /^#/ || /#FFFFFF/ {next}
   !($2 in fb)       {fb[$2]=$1}
   END               {r=$2;for(i=0;i<=r;i++){if(i in fb)print i,fb[i]; else print i,"-1"}}'
```

The `-F[,: ]` tells `awk` to split the words on the line by commas, colons or spaces - this helps me get at the row and column at the start of each line. The line with `/^#/` skips the comment in the first line of ImageMagick text output and all lines that contain `white` or `#FFFFFF`.

Then, I have an array `fb[]` , indexed by image row, that holds the column of the first black pixel on each row. Each time I find a line with a row not in my array `fb[]`, I save it in the array.

At the end, inside `END{}`, I run through `fb[]` printing all rows and indices of first black pixels in those rows. Note that I output `-1` in place of any undefined elements (i.e. those with no non-white pixels) - thanks to @KurtPfeifle for the hint.

Comment: Does it work with non-checkerboard type of images, Mark?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle It does now - thank you! I tested with `convert rose: -threshold 50% -flop txt: ...`

Comment: Test it with `wizard:`, Mark. Yours gives a completely different result from mine. Yours returns only `XXX 0` for me.

Comment: If I create a file with `convert rose: -threshold 50% -flop rose-bw-flopped.png` this is a `70x46` image, your script doesn't work.

Comment: Ooops - I am having a `inverted` day! It all started when OP asked for *first black (or non-white)* pixel... I think it is correct now, thank you.

Comment: But it doesn't work for *any* input file (yet) -- only for the self-created checkerboard... :-)    BTW, I also inverted s.th. earlier -- had swapped rows and columns in earlier version of my answer.  ;-)

Comment: I suck in real `sed`/`awk` coding as soon as it goes beyond the most basic task, and would never dream of doing stuff like you did in this answer. -- Maybe that's why I can't get your solution to work? (My expectation is for it to work with *any* image, not just black+white.) If I change the *board.png* in your `awk` script to whatever other image, my and your solutions output very different results. I think there is still another flaw in your script: it returns all `0`s even for for the checkerboard image.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Mmmm, it seems to work for me. The `-auto-level` is important to make *"your whites white"* - sounds like an advert for washing powder!

Comment: As I said, I'd expect a solution to work for *any* image. Challenge is to *"find first non-white pixel in every row."*

Comment: That's positively all for today! Thanks Kurt :-)

Comment: Nice code. How to change it to print also the last black pixel on each row? For example, `30 2 10` means that on row `30` the first black pixel is on column `2` and the last on column `10`. Also I'd like to save the difference `10-2=8`. Thanks.